# how to properly set subview constraints during initialization?

Tags: swift, layout, uiview, constraints

I know how to set the constraints, but I really need to know how to set it properly.

Basically I have a custom view subclassing UIView, which I need to specify constraints like label needs to be 10pts above the button all the time.

Constraints like this, where do I set it? Right now I am setting the constraints in the `init` function, where I call `layoutIfNeeded` after specifying the constraints. But I've also read that you should set constraints in `layoutSubviews`, but then again I read it somewhere that layoutSubviews will be call many times so it doesn't really make sense to set the constraints there.

Also I was playing with layoutsubviews a little bit, I realized that the constraints I set in layoutsubviews they don't really have any effects on the layout at all. So far I've only successfully setting the constraints by call layoutIfNeeded directly.

Also I am curious, doing I need to set constraints only once or every time something refreshes?

Am I doing this right? Where should I set the constraints in my custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting constraints each time something refreshes (inside LayoutSubviews for example) will churn the constraints and cause a ton of unnecessary work. There's a great WWDC talk about, High Performance Auto Layout.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220

But in general using Interface Builder will save you from yourself; that is, the system will handle adding constraints at the appropriate time in the View lifecycle.

If you must add the constraints programmatically then adding them in the initializer and calling layoutIfNeeded() is a good solution.

Comment: so I should be updating the view immediately when setting the constraints?

Comment: Setting the constraints in the init() will mean layout updates are pending. layoutIfNeeded() will force the Layout Engine to update its layout immediately. Yes, i would call layoutIfNeeded right after setting the constraints.